# How do I find a "pin readout" equivalent for this omnivision cameracube?

Tags: pcb, camera, cmos, imageprocessing

I need to know how to connect this omnivision cameracube to a pcb but I don't know what any of the connections on the bottom of the camera correspond to. How can I figure this out?

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/OVM7690-R20A/884-1019-1-ND/2123272

Comment: It is very hard to help you with this little information. Please provide more details about your project.

Comment: I need to use the cameracube as an image sensor in a very limited volume application. When connecting the cameracube to the printed circuit board I'm wondering how one knows what information to feed into the cameracube and what else needs to be connected within the circuit. Here is the only technical document available for the cameracube:
http://www.ovt.com/uploads/parts/OVM7690_PB(1.0)_web.pdf

Comment: Any update on your progress?  I'm in the same boat as you -- I can't find information on how to connect any of OVT's parts.  It's interesting that you'd have to sign an NDA to get a datasheet, but can easily order in single quantities from Digikey.  What a PITA!

Answer (score 2):

The manufacturer requires that you [request the datasheet](http://www.ovt.com/support/datasheet.php). Searching Google for "site:ovt.com ovm7690" will help you find the [product page](http://www.ovt.com/products/sensor.php?id=45) and from there you can find support -> datasheets in the menu at the top, which leads to the request form linked above.

Comment: Just one word of warning to the OP is that getting camera datasheets can be like pulling hen's teeth. It was going back a while so things may have changed but apart from an NDA they were only interested if you be going to use something like 100K units or more. From memory part of the NDA application was also company information and turnover to determine you were a serious player.